# Postmaster.pid already exists, says PID number is running in directory but no process?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to run a PostgreSQL 9.6.2 db for a new project.

When I type in

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

I get the following error message:

```
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 49425) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
```

When I get a list of all the processes for the folder, it appears:

```
49425
/usr/local/var/postgres
1491484894
5432
/tmp
localhost
```

Then when I try

```
kill 49425
```

It still remains in the list

And when I enter

```
pd
```

The 49425 PID number isn't on the list.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

it says there's a file `/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`, so it won't start.

Instead of starting postgres with `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres` better try `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start`

Comment: I get the following:

$ FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists, 
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 88418) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?

Comment: so maybe there's another instance running?.. did you try to connect to it?

Comment: i've tried to connect to it. i don't have another instance running. it may think there is but i haven't started one today. everytime i try to start one, i get these messages.

Comment: if you stop using `postgres -D ...` and switch to `pg_ctl -D ...` you wont have this problem. to solve it today, remove `/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`

Comment: On Ubuntu WSL, I found the pid file at the following location `/mnt/c/Program Files/PostgreSQL/data/pg96/postmaster.pid`